# docker-compose: Unable to connect app service to mysql database, receive "Error: Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)

Tags: mysql, node.js, docker, docker-compose

I am starting two docker containers through docker-compose.

The contents of `docker-compose.yml` file:

```yaml
version: "3.7"

services:
  app:
    image:  my-app:latest
    ports:  
      - 8000:8000
    working_dir: /usr/app/MyApp
    environment: 
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: myawesomepassword
      MYSQL_DATABASE: myawesomedb
      MYSQL_USER: root
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: myawesomepassword
  mysql:
    image:  mysql:5.6
    volumes:
      - db-data:/var/lib/mysql 
    environment: 
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: myawesomepassword
      MYSQL_DATABASE: myawesomedb
volumes:
  db-data: {}
```

The app is connecting to the database like this:

```js
import mysql from 'mysql2/promise.js';

var config = {
    app: {
        host: 'http://localhost',
        port: '8000'
    },
    database: {
        host: 'host.docker.internal',
        port: 3306,
        database: process.env['MYSQL_DATABASE'],
        user: process.env['MYSQL_USER'],
        password: process.env['MYSQL_PASSWORD']
    }
}

const {host, port, user, password, database } = config.database;

// Error occurs here
const connection = await mysql.createConnection({ host, port, user, password });
```

When the app service attempts to connect to mysql, I receive this error:

`Error: Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)`

Any advice is welcomed. Thank you in advanced

Comment: How are you accessing the database from your app service? Based on the error message, I'm assuming you're pointing to `localhost`, but you should be using `mysql` as the address since it's the name of the db service.

Comment: Hi @FirstOne, thank you for your attention. I have edited the question to include how the app connects to the database. Thank you

Comment: Have you trying using `host: 'mysql'` in the database config? Docker compose should make the other container visible through its name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By the error, it generally means you're pointing the app service to `localhost`, which would mean the app container itself. In your case, you'd be pointing to the host machine.
You need to update the address of the database in your config to point to the other container.

Since you're using `mysql` as the database service name, just update your code to be:

```
database: {
    host: 'mysql',
    port: 3306,
    ...
}
```

Comment: Correct! Tis was what was causing the connection issue!
Thank you for taking the time our of your live and to granting attention to this question! 
May the spirit of joy and the soothing waves of peace be your constant companions. May you dance with the symphony of life, embracing the highs and lows with grace. 
May your journey be blessed with fulfillment. 

Thank you again for the help friend!!!

Answer (score 0):

Changing the database config from:

```js
    database: {
        host: 'host.docker.internal',
        port: 3306,
        database: process.env['MYSQL_DATABASE'],
        user: process.env['MYSQL_USER'],
        password: process.env['MYSQL_PASSWORD']
    }
```

to:

```js
    database: {
        host: 'mysql',
        port: 3306,
        database: process.env['MYSQL_DATABASE'],
        user: process.env['MYSQL_USER'],
        password: process.env['MYSQL_PASSWORD']
    }
```

Resolved the connection issue.

Thank you @FirstOne for your time and attention.

Comment: We posted at the same time lol..